# Laravel : how to get $payment_gateway value

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a feature where, when i create a new booking i can choose the payment method like via xendit or transfer. But when i tried to submit the output of the payment method is still offline payment because of this code `{{$row->gatewayObj ? $row->gatewayObj->getDisplayName() : ''}}` , and not xendit. How do i fix this??

The Controller :

```
public function create(Request $request){
            // $this->checkPermission('news_create');
            $allServices = get_bookable_services();
            $whatsAppBookableServices = ["art", "food", "gear", "car", "hotel"];
            $payment_gateway = ["xendit", "offline payment"];//tambahan Nicho
            $row = new BookingOffline();
            $row->fill([
                'status' => 'publish',
            ]);
            $data = [
                // 'categories'        => NewsCategory::get()->toTree(),
                'row'         => $row,
                'breadcrumbs' => [
                    [
                        'name' => __('Report'),
                        'url'  => 'admin/module/report/booking'
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'  => __('Add Booking By WA'),
                        'class' => 'active'
                    ],
                ],
                'bookableServices' => array_keys($allServices),
                'whatsAppBookableServices' => $whatsAppBookableServices,
                'payment_gateway' => $payment_gateway,//tambahan Nicho
            ];
            return view('Report::admin.booking.create', $data);
        }
```

The Blade file :

```
<td>
    {{$row->gatewayObj ? $row->gatewayObj->getDisplayName() : ''}}
</td>
```

The gatewayObj :

```
function get_payment_gateway_obj($payment_gateway)
{

    $gateways = get_payment_gateways();

    if (empty($gateways[$payment_gateway]) or !class_exists($gateways[$payment_gateway])) {
        return false;
    }

    $gatewayObj = new $gateways[$payment_gateway]($payment_gateway);

    return $gatewayObj;
}
```

Comment: Don't paste the entire controller.. only sieve out the parts that are needed to actually see the issue

Comment: Also, include the gatewayObj and getDisplayName() snippets as part of your question

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestion, i already edit the question, and sorry for lack information

Answer (score 0):

There are still missing pieces to the puzzle, so I cannot provide you with a code snippet to implement.

However, I think you should be able to diagnose it this way:

1. Check your controller.

   Do a die-dump of the $data just above the line containing `return view...`. Like so: `dd($data['payment_gateway'])`

   Then refresh the page in your browser and see if the $data object is exactly how you want it. The value should be ["xendit", "offline payment"].
2. Check your form

   I suppose you have a form element like a `<select></select>`, which is iterating over the values of the `$data['payment_gateway']` array. If you do not have this, how are your users choosing between the payment options?

   Next, make sure that each iteration of payment gateway is being submitted properly. YOu did not include the snippet that handles form submission, but if you're using a `<select>` element, the options each need to be submitted with a  value.

   If we hardcode the select, you will have something like this:

   ```
   <select name="payment_gateway">
       <option value="xendit">Xendit</option>
       <option value="offline">Offline Payment</option>
   </select>
   ```

   So when the server receives this form information, it knows the exact value of payment gateway to use. Dynamically, it could look like this:

   ```
   <select name="payment_gateway">
       @foreach($data['payment_gateways'] as $gateway)
          <option value="{{ $gateway }}">{{ $gateway }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
   ```
3. Intercept the request and check that your payment_gateway is being submitted properly.

   Go to the controller method that handles your form, and do something like `dd($request->all())`

   Then inspect the value of payment_gateway.